# How to fix the lack of Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) in old AMI images which prevents instance launch?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an old AMI which used to run on a c4.large machine.

Since this class is not available an all AZ, I picked a c5.large to restore the image to.

However, when I run terraform to restore, I got this error message:

> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - aws_instance.convertor: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - aws_instance.convertor: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Enhanced networking with the Elastic
>     Network Adapter (ENA) is required for the 'c5.large' instance type.
>     Ensure that you are using an AMI that is enabled for ENA.
>       status code: 400, request id: 7f32e7a1-c201-4db3-9f9e-6da4657ba9c8

How I can find which instance type can accept this old AMI? Or is there anything I can apply to the AMI to work with newer instance type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use AMI which has ENA enabled option.
Follow these instructions:

[Enhanced Networking ENA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html)

Do not forget to set:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id instance_id --ena-support
```